# Regex between double pipes

Tags: java, regex

I have been attempting to get all the values between a double piped string.

My example string is below.

```
Item number 1 || Item number 2 || 168
```

Java Code as follows:

```
final String regex = "?????";
final String string = "Item number 1 || Item number 2 || 168";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

I would like for regex to split and remove whitespace leaving me with:

- Item number 1
- Item number 2
- 168

How can this be accomplished? I have not found a similar answer with double piping.

Comment: do you know you can use `.split`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: Yeah, Regex is unnecessary. Use `.split(" || ")`.

Comment: That's *exactly* why I hate regex.

Comment: `String[] ops = text.split("\\s*\\|{2}\\s*");`

Comment: @BHustus that won't work.  You need a different regexp.

Comment: @S.Jovan I will upvote that if you post it as an answer, and explain why it's correct.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem right, I guess I forgot that Java's split isn't a plaintext split and you have to account for the regex parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method `split()` to split the string around matches.

**Regex**: [`\s*\|\|\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/jsmnPR/1) or `\s*\|{2}\s*`

Details:

- `\s*` 0 or more consecutive occurrences of any whitespace

**Java code**:

```
String text = "Item number 1 || Item number 2 || 168";
String[] ops = text.split("\\s*\\|{2}\\s*");
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/Eorpxd)